# How to sort an Array of JObject?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, c#-4.0

In my code I need sort the Array of `JObject` based on the date. how to do it? my data is like below I need to sort it into descending order.

```
"His": [
        {
        "Date": "6/17/2019 6:00:00 PM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/17/2019 11:08:48 AM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/17/2019 7:38:00 AM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/17/2019 5:00:00 AM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/16/2019 6:16:00 PM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/15/2019 9:20:00 PM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/13/2019 2:00:00 PM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/13/2019 1:37:00 PM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/13/2019 2:39:00 AM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/13/2019 2:11:00 AM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/13/2019 2:08:00 AM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "6/12/2019 3:50:00 PM",
        "StatusMsg": ""
    }
    ]
```

I assigned the result to `JObject`.This is my sample input. any one try to help me. thank you.

Comment: why not deserialize to a regular object model, where you can use all the usual tools? (in addition to being *inconvenient to work with*, a dynamic model like `JObject` has additional overheads, so it is also inefficient)

Answer (score 5):

Like Marc said in the question comments - why not use a regular class:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public His[] His { get; set; }
}

public class His
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string StatusMsg { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public string StatusDate { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize it and take advantage of LINQ:

```
var json = "{\r\n\t\"His\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"Date\": \"3/18/2019 6:30:45 PM\",\r\n            \"StatusMsg\": \"test3\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"Date\": \"3/21/2019 12:13:02 PM\",\r\n            \"Msg\": \"test2\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"StatusDate\": \"3/17/2019 9:26:00 AM\",\r\n            \"Msg\": \"test1\"\r\n        },\r\n    ]\r\n}";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

var sortedList = obj.His.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).ToList();
```

---

**Edit**: If you don't want to use a class then you could do something like this:

```
var json = "{\r\n\t\"His\": [{\r\n\t\t\t\"Date\": \"3/18/2019 6:30:45 PM\",\r\n\t\t\t\"StatusMsg\": \"test3\"\r\n\t\t}, {\r\n\t\t\t\"Date\": \"3/21/2019 12:13:02 PM\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Msg\": \"test2\"\r\n\t\t}, {\r\n\t\t\t\"Date\": \"3/17/2019 9:26:00 AM\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Msg\": \"test1\"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t]\r\n}\r\n";

JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

JArray array = jobj["His"];

JArray sorted = new JArray(array.OrderByDescending(obj => (DateTime)obj["Date"]));
```

This assumes each JSON object will **always** have a property called "Date"

Comment: Don't forget to use `.OrderByDescending()` instead of `.OrderBy()`.

Comment: You dont have to convert to a `List<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response everyone. if i use a regular class i need to mention the fields in the class. But in this case the key value pair may be changed. but the fixed field is date. That is the reason i want to sort the object without regular class.

Comment: @SATHEESHP but in your example, your last object doesn't have "Date" but has "StatusDate"?

Comment: @chris it is not working. The output not in sorted order.

Comment: @SATHEESHP when I run the above code I get the following https://imgur.com/a/CHZVflh

Comment: @chris some times i am getting this error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime for the same input what i was given

Comment: @SATHEESHP do you have an example of an erroring string?